# Is there a way to encrypt a message with Azure Key Vault using a symmetric key?

Tags: java, azure, azure-keyvault

I'm using the Java library to access an Azure Key Vault, and looking at com.azure.security.keyvault.keys.cryptography.CryptographyClient it takes an EncryptionAlgorithm that seem to be able to use symmetric keys. However, you cannot store symmetric keys in Azure Key Vault which then makes me wonder: How do you use for example the EncryptionAlgorithm.A256CBC_HS512?

The only thing I can imagine is to use a jsonWebKey **directly** as a keyIdentifier (as opposed to using the identifier) and then encrypt the message. So, I need to store a jsonWebKey (AES key) as a **secret** in the vault, retrieve the secret and then use it to encrypt. This does not feel secure though since the AES key will then be sent over the Internet (even though it is over https).

So, what is the recommended (secure) process of encrypting a message with a symmetric key using Azure Key Vault.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KV only does asymmetric crypto, and only Keys (asymmetric) exposes crypto operations like encrypt/decrypt sign/verify and so on.

You can always wrap a symmetric key using KV and unwrap the key using KV. But the symmetric crypto operation would be in your Java code.

I wrote an article on some funky KV crypto stuff, and this provides a link to some C# code.
https://michaelhowardsecure.blog/2020/06/05/the-curious-case-of-the-un-enforced-azure-key-vault-rbac-policy/

I hope this helps.

Comment: So the best practice here would be to send the symmetric keys over the Internet? Even if I wrap them, when I unwrap them they'll be in clear text and then sent to my app, right? Also, thanks for the answer!

Comment: if you wrap the symmetric key, it is encrypted until you unwrap it. but yeah, at that point the symmetric key is in the clear in your app.

Comment: I understand that it's in the clear in my app but I guess my question was more if it is sent in the clear from the Key Vault to my app across the Internet (say my app is located in the US while my Key Vault is in Europe, or if they're in the same region but in different networks). If that is the case (which I at this point assume), what would the best practices be to defend against someone, somehow, managing to inspect the https traffic between my app and the key vault. Maybe this is better to post as a new question though?

Comment: Hello - From your app to KV, the network is protected with TLS 1.2, you cannot turn it off. Between Azure data centers, we use IPSec-protected channels. So if any sensitive data flies across the ether, it's protected. Both of these protocols offer end-to-end protections, so you're ok!